# open link with target="_blank" can´t fix it

Tags: php, wordpress, hyperlink

i would like to change a link to target="_blank" (opening in a new window, or tab) but can#t fix it. i´m a fool in php and my try&error-method did´t work. can anybody help me?

**Thank you so much!**

original code from the parallax one theme (wordpress)

```
<?php

if(!empty($parallax_one_contact_info_item_decoded)){    
    foreach($parallax_one_contact_info_item_decoded as $parallax_one_contact_item){
        if(!empty($parallax_one_contact_item->link)){
            echo '<div class="col-sm-4 contact-link-box col-xs-12">';
            if(!empty($parallax_one_contact_item->icon_value)){ 
                echo '<div class="icon-container"><span class="'.esc_attr($parallax_one_contact_item->icon_value).' colored-text"></span></div>';
            }
            if(!empty($parallax_one_contact_item->text)){
                echo '<a href="'.$parallax_one_contact_item->link.'" class="strong">'.$parallax_one_contact_item->text.' </a>';
            }
            echo '</div>';
        } else {
            echo '<div class="col-sm-4 contact-link-box  col-xs-12">';
            if(!empty($parallax_one_contact_item->icon_value)){
                echo '<div class="icon-container"><span class="'.esc_attr($parallax_one_contact_item->icon_value).' colored-text"></span></div>';
            }
            if(!empty($parallax_one_contact_item->text)){
                if(function_exists('icl_translate')){
                    echo '<a href="" class="strong">'.icl_translate('Contact',$parallax_one_contact_item->id.'_contact',esc_attr($parallax_one_contact_item->text)).'</a>';
                } else {
                    echo '<a href="" class="strong">'.esc_attr($parallax_one_contact_item->text).'</a>';
                }
            }
            echo '</div>';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php

if(!empty($parallax_one_contact_info_item_decoded)){    
    foreach($parallax_one_contact_info_item_decoded as $parallax_one_contact_item){
        if(!empty($parallax_one_contact_item->link)){
            echo '<div class="col-sm-4 contact-link-box col-xs-12">';
            if(!empty($parallax_one_contact_item->icon_value)){ 
                echo '<div class="icon-container"><span class="'.esc_attr($parallax_one_contact_item->icon_value).' colored-text"></span></div>';
            }
            if(!empty($parallax_one_contact_item->text)){
                echo '<a target="_blank" href="'.$parallax_one_contact_item->link.'" class="strong">'.$parallax_one_contact_item->text.' </a>';
            }
            echo '</div>';
        } else {
            echo '<div class="col-sm-4 contact-link-box  col-xs-12">';
            if(!empty($parallax_one_contact_item->icon_value)){
                echo '<div class="icon-container"><span class="'.esc_attr($parallax_one_contact_item->icon_value).' colored-text"></span></div>';
            }
            if(!empty($parallax_one_contact_item->text)){
                if(function_exists('icl_translate')){
                    echo '<a target="_blank" href="" class="strong">'.icl_translate('Contact',$parallax_one_contact_item->id.'_contact',esc_attr($parallax_one_contact_item->text)).'</a>';
                } else {
                    echo '<a target="_blank" href="" class="strong">'.esc_attr($parallax_one_contact_item->text).'</a>';
                }
            }
            echo '</div>';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Note: Added `target="_blank"` in each hyperlink.

Comment: Code only answers rarely provide much insight for OP and future visitors, could you perhaps clarify what is different in your answer compared to OP? What did OP do wrong / where was his/her error?

Comment: OP wants to open the link in a different tab and he/she is new to PHP, so I changed the code which need to be added to fulfill OP's requirement and added.

Comment: It's not for my sake, it's for the future visitors / OP.

Comment: please let me know the cause for downvoting :) thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Simply add `target="_blank"` in your anchor tag. For example :

```
echo '<a target="_blank" href="'.$parallax_one_contact_item->link.'" class="strong">'.$parallax_one_contact_item->text.' </a>';
```